# how to pass audio between sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, javax.sound.sampled

Im try to pass audio between sockets but it pass one time in client than clients stops working.
I think the way im writing and sending may be wrong please help me regarding this code
Following is my server code :

```
  public void run(){
    try{
            SetInitialSettings();
            int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * (int) format.getFrameSize();
            System.out.println("length :" +bufferSize);
            out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            readagain=true;
            while(record){
            int count=0;

            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            {

                       if(buffer==null){
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                       }
                       count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                       if (count > 0) {
                       //out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                       //readagain=false;
                           for (int j=0;i<ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.size();j++){
                            ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.get(i).cliOut.write("Audio".getBytes());
                            ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.get(i).cliOut.write('\n');
                            ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.get(i).cliOut.flush();
                            ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.get(i).cliOut.write(buffer,0,count);
                            ser.clientReceiver.audioSender.get(i).cliOut.flush();
                            Thread.sleep(2000);

                               }
                       }

            }            




    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }




    }
```

and following is my client code :

public void run(){

```
    try{
        //audioReceiver = new TAudioReceiver(cli);
        //audioReceiver.start();
        while(true){

            //Thread.sleep(1000);    
            System.out.println("reading token");
            cmd= cli.BufferedReader().readLine();
            System.out.println("token :" +cmd);
            switch (cmd) {
                case "Msg":
                    message = cli.BufferedReader().readLine();
                    cmd="None";
                    break;
            case "File":
              GetFile();
                break;
            case "Audio":
                PlayAudio();
                break;


        }


        }

        //reading msgs here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //throw new InterruptedException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this is the function need to run when "audio" msg received from server to client

```
 public void PlayAudio()throws Exception{

     try{

                    cli.ServerInputStream().read(buffer);


                    audio = buffer;
                    audioIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
                    AudioFormat f = new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1,true, true);
                    ain= new AudioInputStream(audioIn,f, audio.length/f.getFrameSize());
                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, f);
                    try (SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {
                        int bufferSize = (int) f.getSampleRate()* f.getFrameSize();
                        buffer= new byte[bufferSize];
                        int count;
                        while ((count = ain.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                        if (count > 0) {
                          line.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                        }
                        line.drain();
                    }

     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         System.out.println("file" + ex.getMessage());
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code was better. You must write(buffer, 0, count), not write(buffer). Otherwise you are writing junk at the end of each buffer that wasn't read by the last read. Your second piece of code ignores the result of read().

Comment: please check i have replaced write with write(buffer , 0 count)

actually i am reading audio in 2nd code and then trying to read whole buffer. can you please show me the mistake where should i change. as client is one receiver which needs to accept chat msg , file , and audio

Comment: @user1998498 You are still ignoring the result of read. The client copy loop should be the inverse of the server copy loop, not a completely different piece of code. If you got rid of all the extra bits of protocol that you don't need, both loops would be identical.

Comment: please have a look on my this question. now im getting sound : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489953/receiving-same-java-sound-between-sockets